# Else condition always executes... What do I have wrong?

Tags: batch

I'm trying to get this thing to work, but for some reason, even though I think it's correct, it doesn't appear to be honoring the else statement.  As a result, it's like there is no else and it just executes all lines of code.  The purpose is the check is something is running.  If it is, then it is supposed to display a message and leave the command window open so one can see what needs to be done to fix it, then when a key is pressed, the command window closes.  In the event it is not running, it will start it for them  and close the command window so one can't see it.

Here's the output to show what's happening (blank lines removed to conserve space):

```
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>QPROCESS "Pulse.exe" 1>NUL No Process exists for pulse.exe
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>REM 0 means that it's running (ProcessFound) and 1 mean s it's not (ProcessNotFound)
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>REM cmd /k IF (1 EQU 0 goto ProcessFound) ELSE (goto Pr ocessNotFound)
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>REM cmd /k IF 1 NEQ 0 (
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>cmd /k IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>echo In ProcessNotFound In ProcessNotFound
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>REM cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure \JamUI\
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>REM start "" Pulse.exe -tray
C:\Users\me2\Desktop>echo In ProcessFound In ProcessFound
C:\Users\me27\Desktop>REM cls 0
Pulse Secure is running. It must be stopped by right clicking on the icon and clicking Exit.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And here's the code:

```
QPROCESS "Pulse.exe">NUL
REM 0 means that it's running (ProcessFound) and 1 means it's not (ProcessNotFound)
REM cmd /k IF (%ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto ProcessFound) ELSE (goto ProcessNotFound)
REM cmd /k IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
cmd /k IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
     :ProcessNotFound
     echo In ProcessNotFound
     REM cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\
     REM start "" Pulse.exe -tray
) ELSE (
     :ProcessFound
     echo In ProcessFound
 REM    cls
     @echo off
     echo %ERRORLEVEL%
     ECHO.
     ECHO.
     ECHO Pulse Secure is running.
     ECHO It must be stopped by right clicking on the icon and clicking Exit.
     ECHO.
     ECHO.
     PAUSE
     )
REM IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ECHO "Pulse Secure is running.  It must be stopped by right clicking on the icon and clicking Exit."
```

Answer (score 0):

- With `cmd /k` you are spawning a new instance of cmd.exe in the same window.
- the errorlevel in this new cmd.exe refers to the starting of cmd.exe itself, which obviously **was** succesfull, so errorlevel is 0
- simply remove all those unneccessary `cmd /k`
- you might also check for `%errorlevel%`, which doesn't imply `if errorlevel x or greater` what your syntax does.

Without knwing your QPROCESS, you might use conditional execution on fail `||` or success `&&`  see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

```
QPROCESS "Pulse.exe" >NUL 2>&1 || (
    echo In ProcessNotFound
    REM cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\
    REM start "" Pulse.exe -tray
) && (
    echo In ProcessFound
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    ECHO.
    ECHO Pulse Secure is running.
    ECHO It must be stopped by right clicking on the icon and clicking Exit.
    ECHO.
    PAUSE
)
```

Comment: I did what you suggested by removing the cmd /k but it no longer works.  With that removed, it now does not execute the ELSE statement, which it should, since it is now running.  FYI - that was put in there because without it, it always closes the window so fast, there's no way to see why it's failing.  With the cmd -k in there, i can see what's happening.  Also, please not that I'm showing the %errorlevel% and it looks correct as it's executing BOTH ProcessFound and ProcessNotFound in the same script which is why I was saying that the ELSE doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: It didn't work before either. Don't use `:labels` in (code blocks), this won't work.  suggest to use conditional execution on fail `||` or success `&&`, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I used the code snippet you sent directly and it still fails.  How do I know?  Because it's currently running and it did not put the error message up like it should.execute the In ProcessFound part, which it does not and it is in fact running. Without the cmd window not staying up, I cannot tell what is happening, but since it's not showing the message, one can only assume it's executing the ProcessNotFound part.  Now you can see what I've been struggling with!  :(

Comment: As I mentioed I don't know your Qprocess, what happen if you run `QPROCESS "Pulse.exe"` in an open cmd window without redirecting output?

Comment: USERNAME              SESSIONNAME         ID    PID   IMAGE                                     
>me2                           console                      1     7000  pulse.exe

Comment: It might be a better idea than to parse the output of QPROCESS with a `for /f`.